# Having trouble with CSS for a grid layout with squares, rows and columns

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am attempting to create what I thought would be a simple layout of divs, however the css is proving to be a little more complicated than I initially thought. Each of the DIVs need to stand alone (so I cannot use a div to contain the SQUARES and ROW, and another div to hold the COLUMN) for ease of responsiveness.

I am trying to achieve this...

[image]

With a narrow responsive version like this...

[image]

But I can't seem to get the ROW container to sit below the SQUARE containers. This is the code I have so far and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulStarkey/f65f8q49/).

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="content">

    <div id="item" class="square">

        text

    </div>

</div>

<div id="content">

    <div id="item" class="square">

        text

    </div>

</div>

<div id="content">

    <div id="item" class="horiz">

        text

    </div>

</div>


<div id="content">

    <div id="item" class="vert">

        text

    </div>

</div>


<div id="content">

    <div id="item" class="vert">

        text

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper{
    max-width: 95%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    background: #00F;
}

#content{
    margin-top: 25px;
    background: #F00;
    display: inline;
}

#item{
    background: #F0F;
    text-align: center;
}

.square {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;    
    margin:1%;
    float:left;
}


.horiz {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;    
    margin:1%;
    float:left;
    display: block;
}

.vert {
    width:100px;
    height:200px;   
    margin:1%;
    float:left;

}
```

Comment: For narrow pages, how do you want the div's to look like?

Comment: Edited post to show narrow layout.

Comment: Will the div's always have specific dimensions, for example, squares 100x100 regardless of the screen size?

Comment: No, they will have to change to ensure they fill screen on web page and fill screen down to mobile phone. I was going to use the @media queries for this but can't even get the initial layout needed.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you are using `id` incorrectly. You should NEVER have duplicate `id`s. Use classes instead. Note you can have more than one class per element, eg: `class="content item square"`

Comment: I will also mention a completely overkill solution: Masonry for jquery: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of creating a responsive grid similar to what you need.

I would start with the following HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="item square s1">text square 1</div>
    <div class="item square s2">text square 2</div>
    <div class="item horiz">text horiz</div>
    <div class="item vert v1">text vert v1</div>
    <div class="item vert v2">text vert v2</div>
</div>
```

and look at the following CSS:

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 90vw;
    height: 45vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #00F;
    position: relative;
}
.item {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: pink;
}
.square {
    width: 23.75%;
    height: 47.5%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2%;
}
.s1 {
    left: 1%;
}
.s2 {
    left: 25.75%;
}
.horiz {
    width: 48.5%;
    height: 46.5%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 51.5%;
    left: 1%;
}
.vert {
    width: 23.75%;
    height: 96.0%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2%;
}
.v1 {
    left: 50.5%;
}
.v2 {
    left: 75.25%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

The trick is to set the units for the containing block using viewport-percentage lengths
(vw units, http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths).

I set the width to be 90% of the viewport width and the height to be half of that
value so you get a block that is 2:1 in aspect ratio.

You can then use absolute positioning to place the various elements within the grid
using percentage values for the width, height and margins.

The result is responsive, but the content can overflow since all the child blocks have
fixed dimensions (that may be okay in your mobile application).

You can use a similar approach for the narrow-screen layout, using a 1:2 width:height
ratio instead of 2:1.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/nwgcLcc0/

Note: It would have been a lot easier to add a wrapper around the two-squares+horizontal set of elements and then a second wrapper around the two vertical elements.

Comment: Hi Paul, glad to help, the solution need quite a bit of precise arithmetic, but it gets the job done. I wish there was a simpler approach. All the best!